# Log partial likelihood of a Cox Model

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I need to use Cox's partial likelihood method to establish a Cox's proportional hazards regression model with the significant predictors of my model.

I am wondering if the `coxph()` function in `R` does this automatically or if there is a special function which can?

I found the following function in the link below, but I cannot seem to find a package that contains it:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survcomp/versions/1.22.0/topics/logpl

Comment: Packages are stored at  CRAN subdomain of r-project.org. Google search produces this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survcomp/index.html. Now that you have its source code you may need to also search on how to install packages that need compilation.

Comment: (That assumed you had read the content and followed the link to its new home in BioConductor.) Voting to close since requests for package recs and searches are OT on SO.

Comment: Yes. I got this to work. Thank you!